# Laravel 6 null results when request from radio button

Tags: html, laravel, request, radio-button, laravel-6

i cant' see any results here when i'm trying to get value of my radio button. Whats wrong??

Here my HTML

```
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
  <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="salahpenggunaanberkas" name="alasan" value="Salah penggunaan berkas">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="salahpenggunaanberkas">Salah penggunaan berkas</label>
</div>
```

And here my controller

```
public function save_laporkan_pendaftar(Request $request) {
  echo $alasan = $request->alasan;
}
```

Comment: Where is your form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    //blade file
    <form action="{{route('post.stroe')}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other  
      <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form> 
    // Controller 
    public function review(Request $request)
        {

                $this->validate($request,[
                    'gender' => 'required'
                ]);


                $post             = new Post();
                $post->gender      = $request->gender;
                $post->save();
                Toastr::success('Your Post Successfully submited','Success');
                return redirect()->back();

        }

 public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::latest()->get();
        return view('admin.reviews.index',compact('posts '));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this.

```
$alasan = $request->get('alasan');
```

Answer (score 0):

use `request()` global helper and I assume that you don't have any problems with sending a request to the controller! right.

Here are some examples of how to use `request()` global helper anywhere in the project.

```
request()->input('alasan')
request()->get('alasan')

/// or get all inputs
request()->all()
```